# AS2 Flash button url not working

Tags: flash, button, actionscript

I have the following actionscript code on my button

```
on(release){
getURL("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
}
```

When I click it, nothing happens, no compiler errors. I'm scratching my head here because its just a simple button :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that event handler has not an object associated with its action. Give that button a name, say *my_button* and in the time line add this action code:

```
    this.my_button.onRelease = function() {
      getURL("http://www.google.com", "_blank");    
    }
```

That will solve your problem :)

Comment: Hello Joe, it doesn't work for me :/ all i have on my stage is just one button, just so i make sure nothing else is interfering with it.